# How can I remove old/deleted data from SpiderOak/SpiderOakOne via CLI?

Tags: spideroak

- Version: 7.2.0
- OS: Arch Linux

The updated GUI is, to be honest, quite nice but not so responsive.

When in the `Manage` tab, clicking on "Remove data" above that status bar does nothing. While I know [I can select single files](https://spideroak.support/hc/en-us/articles/115002890366-Removing-Data-From-an-Account) that I deleted and which have a date shown in the appropriate column, I can't possibly do this for every single file I once deleted in the synced folders, right?

Their help page for the [--purge option](https://spideroak.support/hc/en-us/articles/115001932006) says:

> The command line option --purge permanently deletes a directory or file, including any historical versions, from your account. It is not reversible.

But I am not keen on perma-deleting the current version of a file. Hm. :/

So in the GUI, is it safe to just select (one of) the parent folders and remove them?

Comment: The only reference in the [CLI](https://spideroak.support/hc/en-us/articles/115001891343-Command-Line-Reference) seems to be [--purge-historical-versions](https://spideroak.support/hc/en-us/articles/115001893323--purge-historical-versions) available only on One.

Comment: @harrymc Ohhh! Sweet. Reading the help page for that command right now. Will check back in.

Comment: @harrymc Please post your comment as a reply so I can mark this as solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are looking in the 
[CLI](https://spideroak.support/hc/en-us/articles/115001891343-Command-Line-Reference)
for the option of
[--purge-historical-versions available](https://spideroak.support/hc/en-us/articles/115001893323--purge-historical-versions)
which is only available on One :

> This removes some or all historical versions that were uploaded from the local computer, on a schedule you can specify. This can free up space in your account.

On Linux it is used as follows :

```
SpiderOakONE --purge-historical-versions --verbose
```

See the manual for options for the selective removal of entries.